# Komodo Edit userscript js -Where are doCommands for close file?

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I am writing a custom macro/userscript (in JS) for Komodo Edit.

The final thing I need to do is to CLOSE the file in the editor after I save it, but I cannot locate a list of doCommands.

I can use this to save the file, but I do not know how to close it.
ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_saveAll');

The Komodo docs point here:
http://docs.komodoide.com/SDK/commandid

But as you can see the page is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where to find a list of doCommands, but I use the following:

SAVE file:

```
ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_saveAll');
```

CLOSE file:

```
ko.commands.doCommand('cmd_bufferClose');
```